# Using javascript datetime in clojurescript

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript, java-interop

I want to show date and time in Clojurescript, but anything I tried did not work.
Can anyone help with an example? I tried to use JavaScript datatime in different syntax ways, but none of them worked.
Thank you.

**Update**

I tired these but they did not work:

```
(. (js/Date))
(js/Date.)
(now (js/Date))
(js/Date.new)
(js/Date.new.)
(.new (js/Date)
```

I just wont to show the current date and time on the screen. Inside a **[:h3]** tag in the **.cljs** file.

Comment: It's very unclear what you actually want. You write that you tried some things - can you post them? What exactly do you mean by "show date"? If you mean just creating a date as in `new Date()` in JS, it's `(js/Date.)` in CLJS.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov that did not work for me, the page goes blank when I use that.

Comment: @cfrick I added the things I tried. The problem is I don't know how to use java introp and did not fond anything helpful by searching.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov should [:h3 (js/Date.)] show the date? Or am I doing that wrongly?

Comment: If you don't get any other error, does the dev-console give any clues?

Comment: What is the expected date (or date + time) format? `[:h3 (.now js/Date)]` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, but you probably want to format it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```clj
(.toLocaleString (js/Date.))
;; => "22/11/2022, 17:17:22"
```

and in `[:h3]`:

```clj
[:h3 (.toLocaleString (js/Date.))]
```

If you want other formatting you can mix and match [the available methods on a Date instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) using [interop](https://lwhorton.github.io/2018/10/20/clojurescript-interop-with-javascript.html).